# change alignment and position of android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I have main layout activity_user_profile which include these three layout: First_layout,

Second_layout,

list_item.

**activity_user_profile.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



    <include layout="@layout/first_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <include layout="@layout/second_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    <include layout="@layout/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

As seen in the image, there is a white gap between bottom and list_item.xml.
How can shift this layout to right and extend it to bottom of the page?

Update

first_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="UserProfile"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="7.03"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

second_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Main3Activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextAddress"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Post"
        android:onClick="insert"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post other twol layout xml also?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: but  your code working with me fine

Comment: I want to remove the white area

Comment: you mean that whit area that overwrite  textview?   you can use bottom padding @ for that textview

Answer (score 1):

Have searched this for a long time and concluded this :

Remove,

```
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_weight="1"
```

**Check that :**

1. Scroll view must have a single child (i.e all views must be included
   within a single root layout inside scroll view)
2. ScrollView works when your page size is greater the default height
   of the screen.

Comment: It is not affecting at all :(

Comment: The presentation of layout

Comment: it is working but I lost ScrollView on list_item.xml.

Comment: remove **-->**  android:fadingEdge="none"

    android:isScrollContainer="true" from scroolview

Comment: just use --  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

Comment: not yet I think I should change the height of list_item.xml

Comment: after spending lot of time, i come to know that your ScrollView will not work because linearlayout below have used **android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3"** this will not be applicable.

Comment: what is the solution? do you have any contact like skype?

Comment: not now. once i get solution i will post here. please upvote if this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
Replace your  `activity_user_profile.xml` by this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



     <include layout="@layout/first_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <include layout="@layout/second_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <include layout="@layout/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made following changes in your layout.....
See code below

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <include layout="@layout/first_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <include layout="@layout/second_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <include layout="@layout/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: it is changed but not my interest. First, the button is disappeared. The list_item.xml is not extended

Answer (score 0):

The child of the scroll view should have it's height set to "wrap_content" to allow scrolling.

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Change this to:

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```